# How to do "Internationalization" in Cocos2D-X?

Tags: internationalization, cocos2d-x

I am new to Cocos2D-X, I'd like to know how to do "Internationalization" (Texts in English, Chinese, French, Japanese, etc) in Cocos2D-X.
    I know how to do "Internationalization" in Android, IOS. Is there a way to do
internationalization in Cocos2D-X directly or should I do
internationalization for each platform (IOS, Android, Winphone, etc) I publish the App to ?
    Could anyone help me ?
    Thank you very much.

Best regards!

Answer (score 0):

You can create an excel sheet file for all strings resources used in game in various languages as columns and one column for key. You columns will be like.

```
KEY | ENGLISH | HINDI | CHINESE
```

Now you can export a JSON file from this excel sheet and parse it and store in a key, value  pair object on the basis of device language while loading or you can manually give option to change language in game.

You can get current language in cocos2dx using :

```
ccLanguageType currentLanguageType = CCApplication::sharedApplication()->getCurrentLanguage();
switch (currentLanguageType)
{
case kLanguageEnglish:
    // load json file 
    break;
case kLanguageChinese:
    break;
case kLanguageHindi:
    break;
default:
    break;
}
```